# VBScript text spammer, index wont go above 31 when using "loop until"

Tags: indexing, vbscript

I recently wrote a piece of code that automatically sends messages. I'm currently experiencing an issue where my index wont go above 31.
When testing, my script doesn't send more than 31 messages. (I'm quite new to this, please don't mind if i made an easy mistake)
This is my code:

```
wscript.sleep 3000
Set wshShell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim index
index = 0
do
wscript.sleep 100
wshshell.sendkeys "Test"
wshshell.sendkeys "{enter}"
index = index + 1
loop until index > 50
```

How can i make it send more than 31 messages? Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you tried increasing the delay between `SendKeys()`? Hundred Milliseconds is pretty fast. Also what is `SendKeys()` sending to *(Command Window, IE instance, Bespoke Application etc.)*? Text Spammer eh?, sounds malicious...

Comment: Your **`Do... Loop Until`** is working perfectly fine. You can give it try by replacing both **`...sendkeys...`** statements with **`wscript.echo index`** and it will give you msgbox 50 times. Coming back to question from @Lankymart, where are you sending your `sendkeys`...?